# Firefox 4 crashing in VNC

Tags: kubuntu, vnc, firefox

On my desktop PC I've been using Kubuntu 10.04 for about a year. Recently I've updated Firefox to version 4 using aptitude and the mozilla-team/firefox-stable repository.

Since then, I can't run it when I'm logged in through a VNC session. Firefox crashes immediately: when I try to run it from the console I get this error:

```
###!!! ABORT: X_ShmPutImage: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter); 3 requests ago: file /build/buildd/firefox-4.0.1+build1+nobinonly/build-tree/mozilla/toolkit/xre/nsX11ErrorHandler.cpp, line 203
###!!! ABORT: X_ShmPutImage: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter); 3 requests ago: file /build/buildd/firefox-4.0.1+build1+nobinonly/build-tree/mozilla/toolkit/xre/nsX11ErrorHandler.cpp, line 203
```

Firefox works fine when I run it directly from the PC. Firefox 3.x worked fine also from a VNC session.
I tried to turn off the hardware acceleration from the Firefox preferences, but that doesn't fix the problem.

`firefox --sync`, `firefox -safe-mode` and `firefox -ProfileManager` also crash the same way.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Edit: additional info.

I run vnc (RealVNC 4.1.1) from xinetd, this is the config I use:

```
service Xvnc
{
        type = UNLISTED
        disable = no
        socket_type = stream
        protocol = tcp
        wait = yes
        user = root
        server = /usr/bin/Xvnc4
        server_args = -inetd :1 -desktop vnc5901 -query localhost -geometry 1160x675 -depth 16 -once -DisconnectClients=0 -NeverShared passwordFile=/path/to/vnc/password -render
        port = 5901
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved in Firefox 5.